# How to specify a return of an array of unknown size in Chapel

Tags: function, return-type, chapel

I tried to rely on type inference for a function with signature:

    `proc mode(data: [?]int)`

but the compiler said it could not resolve the return type (which is a warning in in itself I guess given there are only two return statements). I tried:

    `proc mode(data: [?]int): [?]int`

but the compiler then said there was an internal error:

`internal error: CAL0057 chpl Version 1.13.1.518d486`

What is the correct way of specifying that the length of an array returned by a function can only be known at run time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the domain/size of the array being returned cannot be described directly in the function prototype, I believe your best bet at present is to omit any description of the return type and lean on Chapel's type inference machinery to determine that you're returning an array (as you attempted).  For instance, here is a procedure that reads in an array of previously unknown size and returns it:

```
proc readArrFromConsole() {
  var len = stdin.read(int);
  var X: [1..len] real;
  for x in X do
    x = stdin.read(real);

  return X;
}

var A = readArrFromConsole();
writeln(A);
```

Running it and typing this at the console:

```
3 1.2 3.4 5.6
```

Generates:

```
1.2 3.4 5.6
```

Your question mentions multiple return statements, which opens up the question about how aggressively Chapel unifies types across distinct arrays.  A simple example with multiple arrays of the same type (each with a unique domain, size, and bounds) seems to work:

```
proc createArr() {
  var len = stdin.read(int);
  if (len > 0) {
    var X: [1..len] real;
    return X;
  } else {
    var Y: [-1..1] real;
    return Y;
  }
}

var A = createArr();
writeln(A);
```

To understand why the compiler couldn't resolve the return type in your example may require more information about what your procedure body / return statements contained.

Comment: This is what I thought and had been doing, so good to know that is the idiomatic approach – thanks for taking the time to write this. However, I have a function that the compiler is refusing to infer a return type, and is complaining, and not compiling. I think I need to take this specific case to the Chapel bugs mailing list.

Comment: It turns out there was a third return statement I had missed. The two I knew of were arrays of int but the other was array of real. A very "I messed up" situation, as clearly the compiler cannot resolve this. I am still glad I asked the question though, things in the answer were very educational on totally different issues.

Comment: It'd be nice to beef up the error message in such cases to point to the return statements that couldn't be unified and the types they were trying to return...

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this from time to time in recursive functions, in situations where omitting the return type fails; in this case I create a `record` which is an array with its domain, *e.g.*:

```
record stringarray {
  var D: domain(1);
  var strs : [D] string;
}
```

and then define the recursive array to return one of those records:

```
proc repeats() : stringarray {
  var reps: stringarray;

  //...

  for child in children do {
    childreps = child.repeats();
    for childrep in childreps do
      reps.push_back(childrep);    
  }

  //...
  return reps;
}
```