# Chapel-1.16.0 pre-release Internal error (-999) what other approach possible to a prior domain-size agnostic declaration?

Tags: chapel

### Prototyping has returned a [chapel](/questions/tagged/chapel) internal error:

while a purpose of this particular setup is neither of interest or relevant,
the compiler finished with a following debug-notice,
for which any advice on collision-avoiding syntax would be appreciated:

```
<TiO>-IDE-Debug::____________________________________________________

.code.tio.chpl:77: internal error: IMP0586 chpl Version 1.16.0 pre-release (-999)

Note: This source location is a guess.

Internal errors indicate a bug in the Chapel compiler ("It's us, not you"),
and we're sorry for the hassle.  We would appreciate your reporting this bug -- 
please see http://chapel.cray.com/bugs.html for instructions.  In the meantime,
the filename + line number above may be useful in working around the issue.
```

<sub>( the compiler-team will obviously have some additional interest & worries about the internal handling of the observed situation, which is not the primary intent or subject of this post )</sub>

---

### [The code, live @](https://tio.run/##5Vttcxo5Ev7Or@giW2VwYMbYiRPjxFtgkw13OHbZZHNVHEuJGQFTnreVZox9qfz183VLMzBj4wTY4E3qZqtiGCR1q9X99NOS1pqwkLt3d6Y5@C5PwdyGN13n7KjaPmmB4C6LuA29YyWmX7UCf@SMY8EiJ/AhFMHQ5V4d8POsU7V3HHih43LxzmXjPkge1QGq7V/OG933g@7Z4LjZaVwOTtoXUO3MXqp3nXbzEqru0GUS/7AI/xZghUfGMuQWiiuB50jp@GOgceE5NLr0t1yg4eaanvBhPK7X17JTXjEzlsIcOr7p2nWwmO8HEYwc305ms3RjPed8cytwXZzVbh24EIGog2vjwkSx8HFlasBvnAhkxKL4fsexx654Hba3t6FnBmFkWmoVTTlhgqdfakZt3xSxHzkeN3lkmafYaYTLZ/AbXt/bqYMZeSG2Dt0qNvO5qO7uv9rdMWzu8ohjJwOnYqA/GNiuDy3SEWr3VEk0t5Rn0LqMOY6kfEsGsbA4Nd82yfuqyz2Xre7Hc/z3uNs@@1D9@OGkdVHtti671eq2CbHk0MUJHX6vAa@ZAHYZBeGnRvf4/eDiw8ngt9aHuhIiNiWl0/4waHR@27CU00Z3cNE63rCUxsVFTooGEnQIX0bgD8JgygW8nfnLy3stOgPp/IdD2qK2s7NzWJjFB7XA@HEsLrFFzTB083st2EngMcfHFp@TxpW015fDmb@S3gCNOvSS9n0MNuaW9l@UD8E09Ze9Xf3FY7db1xzkJJj66Mgeh@FtxKvTQNjAXGfse9xHwSJyRsyKZF5Gc6My9Jzt6Dbk2mrFaiqjeJhX5HI5Rc7@WQcvlhFpM@TcJ2SfNYcoAHYdODaYHcfnTDTcMR8KZhBw1F/uvZyhl9II4dljkTXBBQCGSJ3MYiQCLzdkqkBhBbd8/EmQ4YL5duAdrjzkI55Oz0NsMBCSRVQqa1trkQbiqqs/ltDH4Cs/NunHTSsYhCUtZaUsiw@1f7vCQ9BeQLZgoZ@K04@dEv2lGPv1pDF3uUpeDWzSVE2a8yb5FmX4vFg/c3v5Gb1pCmYfQXsE0YSDrcLAVGgT6FeoB7tFj6e0Ncu7SdoeYg8uLeEM8Z3tCMzT7i05NXUcxb6V8qQoIL@vrGpoaKMI1@EYcreYJ/GLJKEY7xGOyiUFjSMpUgIPaQDzbxN9QiU4mYHWWkceOhi4nPnE2TSr25L6F8cfccF9C6OTWRMMYnG7srqoiI2sQHjYHUWjlqj2lkhVIBOiaGXRlcdeucPR0RFMoiiUddPEaLSugmsuRm4wNZCHmMzcO3ixu7O398rc29/frx282rxGGAYZ3F30oGmOF8LxkrJW8fw0AL4LH9647XDRbK54pkop@3t19Fh0NZ@5aWppn57vvHy9D9QAfudCUgwQwTV2KFowAaLnYwIoVQ8ODsqbV/lDECH/7k4wQjXLBTewdOmErxiMYy6lsXk92jk7Sc16kHyjCrjgKVxpNEg4OrKxUrEdITbESJMI6jCQi@XVAYzwZsoJAmQgxC2MsDogaRNM@1hkAHziMA1irGlYiGtkOaSXwjrBwwBZDUJGRBYkTavV1Scf6jWXnCswQCzQlY9hIQgpJMCRpTGJPFcp5yBvErECbmmQ7ZS6HkImlUirG0BlAjSoz5C6PQeXkNGPvSFamA0RkYjgUR5BZjKKXVoMpHZXCilFEKP1aACsZmNuPA1AFRBEloCoz8izKYsbtoOEpQZlA@c4jialciXFIhMM41muzdLm04M3dcfdzOBwf/B5m2XH/rJkwyz6/p@g6ouDGU@PfeQXgXutyI7rwlZPc6PSbgVxV/G1EXMlL8/NpFaiVt5aWYtfjt@fdwbvz05bphfYsculmWK7qWGpIVS0ko613RpWE77CVqRhtmMjZCCcCvw@0DoqRWyVIMobV@Z1qsz9J6tMyATzYF2V1iMaGCIIaLR26imJYFqh3aSyqrowig2tIHzW4z/eWIX9Sa6xbv91LZxEUGMWosivH5D8414qqw/P36r2@o3T//q8t1WJ0NOi9AAJTUoiPOG9Sshh4cu8BKGtiMH52SdVh5yqIuPRMkQ9fmZ1E@8n89JHrE5hxBDg7fqyHM1MIKIKj2yDvFTwdo/wvHg8NLNT@naYVtIpLIzUsppqDzIWScqsNQrFH7y6@jmLrCeotdbFnR@28vo50/HL/UzMs6HL9Z6Yiv2cw6EPzuIhiwZb30MDpMCLB6//5SKuNpsfARmngw0rxrrtmmOgo0cr5h8GiFebt/3KHRCjuxj4v0IQ0lkG1Q4ynQchwp8xRvfsx4pCBYcKKvo9gIhd8XVkYk2Qhr2NNN3FIhKriiv0jRhrHUA1NKYSykolVB22OJZylTXqTZT5DkflN8xDARVSXJcnKAUF4AIRuSGdsGDqPph4Zs7riM5iXJpByN8bhq6saXQuqXQiPmLzkePrmjEXIZV1REeTIB5PwKEymPKR4H/GmIVs40l868FTssqwu1N7BW3E9X8Y0OQiClxmWUh@mtyH90zIyZCJMRfryDsTzthBkouRh3wkwqwb0/nc8HaRPHKrOLRZ0uL1vEsgSrL8BBZalGsw5wr/xvFv0V9QeanSjR1YMj3tPFp7y27FiTijhDjCG6x70Rn9GRudM9/ThK5y5Gf3RkkaZ7bLTysPmWsFx69SXU2nBV8KGzowSM7u5icahXmxkKkTcszfh8t71QU9lxmq/zY/nUZlxn/LqhU1Wmz65/mezUU9lWW/PJVBnuoIhabzE/63cgytjF2tG4uHkaLblPoub2XEPQklmE6QbquXmCYix6XKg4FlwVSwEBMUJWJd5QPtB1ZdZygtB8obVnjT9kgylYQJu6ZsqM5rk51dG6ZONEl@qf/kE/0Rrh39eFa5aL2b5cUFG94qI9LNLhnNtrhCrNLYGD@QSdRu@LPZbZ0qOUx1@PPbRXuLjEM6WaAjCB0YWJQHwsPAIFbD5BV@Ii7J4IpuZU24G@qQGTk3FEzz@3HoZHG4aZt8x5sPuasZh/MSRu14ds6OG53W4PTspNV568ceg/xtPypuYiG4T5swRIcTO2oGqCo17UxGgQ4PvAam@FOGpPCmpO86qLfNzNvm7O1l5u0lvv3KGvbetf/VOoFG8@z3Vl/39Fh07sayVEYtBJ9u6ArKZrhEcskrT670tPKzSCe54HUwLaG5MzTo29XOI4NkudQ3x9jYDZW5Tf6GGypoizm3xC@0Pbzs5vCjW8OFJQHqR94XRiK/bG2TeciC3yxz8t5oB5G2fOXhYtyveGiQxy5XPYQgTY2q1BJ/7FX6X71/9RCscv2b1H9DEZBcylxYcj1WcxGQeYuqLi9bdmm4zBh1hcKLSq9856evvR5Y5qnAoVCYCifirl9aOGZxzkQ7AUYfv0RGRQf3dShWIPOqAkU0oqQ9TgOOMZQpsfIbbsXqrkOPCpZ@JTkR0f1oBHptOLZC3W8evCVHb1lFkoO3R@dQzOQGLfQZSnVQ2y0J7ZP8RGTP6ZMy5JizEYvZCKLUGVwVK9mjvodXELnLQsntkroVbNA/H30nkobnWCKQHOHPlpjNULleLPuKlFHUVoBiL61tUMgubGOtl1wS3k4/YEd1/5X6c5dTepfq9CiImGsUSftU@ZkHFf@NqPbQE4/UdEjUgjS14ixQg17StU@MiaPqjT98jK3mH0MENpplj0ytZoHdKtkv/dz/bFGsrKV5GkRraJ50/bs0T7de1tA86frXNS9kGNDd3X@tERac8m5RqXm3qNS806XmXVJq/g8) `<TiO>-IDE::`

```
/* ---------------------------------------SETUP-SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/ use Time;
/* ---------------------------------------SETUP-SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/ var aStopWATCH_RND_GEN: Timer;
/* ---------------------------------------SETUP-SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/ var aStopWATCH_LIN_ALG: Timer;
/* ---------------------------------------SETUP-SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/ var aStopWATCH_MAT_REC: Timer;
/* ---------------------------------------SETUP-SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/ var aStopWATCH_ARR_REC: Timer;
config const n_power =         5;
config const L_size  =      1000;
       const indices = 1..L_size;
       const aDomain = {indices, indices};

       var   A: [aDomain] real(64); // real(32); // may've shown some byte-word alignment artifacts
       var   B: [aDomain] real(64); // real(32); // may've shown some byte-word alignment artifacts
       const dtype =    "-real(64)";
       var   S: [aDomain] real(64); // real(32); // OK: must've been set real(64) to avoid /LinearAlgebra.chpl:535: error: type mismatch in assignment from real(64) to real(32)

/* -----------------------------------------------------------------*/ use Random;
/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/     aStopWATCH_RND_GEN.start();
    Random.fillRandom(  A );
    Random.fillRandom(  B );
/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/     aStopWATCH_RND_GEN.stop();
/* 

   ============================================ */

proc arrMUL( arrA: [?DA] real(64),
             arrB: [?DB] real(64)
             ) {                      /*
                                         <Brad> If the domain/size of the array being returned cannot be described directly in the function prototype,
                                                I believe your best bet at present is to omit any description of the return type and lean on Chapel's type inference machinery
                                                to determine that you're returning an array

                                                >>> https://stackoverflow.com/a/39420337/3666197

                                                */
     var                       arrC: [aDomain] real(64);
                                      /*
                                                <TiO>-IDE-Debug::____________________________________________________

                                                .code.tio.chpl:77: internal error: IMP0586 chpl Version 1.16.0 pre-release (-999)

                                                Note: This source location is a guess.

                                                Internal errors indicate a bug in the Chapel compiler ("It's us, not you"),
                                                and we're sorry for the hassle.  We would appreciate your reporting this bug -- 
                                                please see http://chapel.cray.com/bugs.html for instructions.  In the meantime,
                                                the filename + line number above may be useful in working around the issue.

                                                */

 /*  var                       arrC: [{1..arrA.dim( 1 ).length(),       // ..#arrA.dim( 1 ),
                                       1..arrB.dim( 2 ).length()        // ..#arrB.dim( 2 )
                                       }
                                      ] real(64);

                                                <TiO>-IDE-Debug::____________________________________________________

                                                .code.tio.chpl:49: error: unresolved call '[domain(2,int(64),false)] real(64).dim(1)'
                                                $CHPL_HOME/modules/internal/ChapelArray.chpl:1215: note: candidates are: _domain.dim(d: int)
                                                $CHPL_HOME/modules/internal/ChapelArray.chpl:1218: note:                 _domain.dim(param d: int)

                                                */
  // forall      (row, col) in arrC.domain {    // [ROW:77] reports: internal error: IMP0586 chpl Version 1.16.0 pre-release (-999)
     forall      (row, col) in     aDomain {    // [ROW:78] reports: internal error: IMP0586 chpl Version 1.16.0 pre-release (-999) 
        for                              i in arrA.dim( 2 ) do
             arrC[row, col] += arrA[row, i]
                             * arrB[     i, col];
     }
     return  arrC;
}

proc arr_REC_POW( arrM: [?D] real(64),
                  n:          int(64) // int(32) failed:
                                      //      <- config const n_power = 5 // .code.tio.chpl:64: error: unresolved call 'arr_REC_POW([domain(2,int(64),false)] real(64), int(64))'
                  ):    [ D] real(64) {     /* 
                                                <Brad> If the domain/size of the array being returned cannot be described directly in the function prototype,
                                                       I believe your best bet at present is to omit any description of the return type and lean on Chapel's type inference machinery
                                                       to determine that you're returning an array

                                                       >>> https://stackoverflow.com/a/39420337/3666197

                                                <TiO>-IDE-Debug::____________________________________________________

                                                .code.tio.chpl:56: error: unable to resolve return type of function 'arr_REC_POW'
                                                .code.tio.chpl:56: In function 'arr_REC_POW':
                                                .code.tio.chpl:61: error: called recursively at this point


                                                // The ? operator is called the query operator, and is used to take
                                                // undetermined values like tuple or array sizes and generic types.
                                                // For example, taking arrays as parameters. The query operator is used to
                                                // determine the domain of A. This is uesful for defining the return type,
                                                // though it's not required.

                                                //                  (c) 2017 Ian J. Bertolacci, Ben Harshbarger
                                                // Originally contributed by Ian J. Bertolacci, and updated by 8 contributor(s).

                                                        >>> https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/chapel/>
                                                */

     if      n < 1 then return         arrM;
     else               return arrMUL( arrM, arr_REC_POW( arrM, n - 1 ) );
}

/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/     aStopWATCH_ARR_REC.start();

   forall (row, col)             in S.domain {
         S[row, col] = arr_REC_POW( A, n_power )[row,col]
                     + arr_REC_POW( B, n_power )[row,col];
   }
/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/     aStopWATCH_ARR_REC.start();
/* 

   ============================================ */
```

---

reduced from `<TiO>-IDE` ( pity no code-folding productivity, like in other IDE environments. Agree with Ben, the experiments-under-review self-documenting layouts could be much readable as per individual preferences )

still

> `chpl:30: internal error: IMP0586 chpl Version 1.16.0 pre-release (-999)`

`chpl:30:` being:

```
forall      (row, col) in    aDomain {
```

[**>>> aClickThrough**-with-an-updated-code, no syntax warnings but (-999) **@**](https://tio.run/##xVdbc5tGFH7nV@zQzhQpgOxM2gerTgYkJdGMJHuEPHmgCrMWK3unXDSA7LSO/3rUsxckEAjXdu3uA0jLd85@57q7i2u8IsFmg2rGOiVoRkPSVZQbnCDsZPHqizXrffamk773aTA54Z9N9ki6@5jRcOJZo0@NmLE186aDXiPGmk6rGGURR0t6heCVZijyVvEtSdDplvqv3TJi5KX0b4JyxPHR0VFXkViBoJFPFyQFxLFpCvgeAvfjENMIEHcSrOdS98BIYhl7hKwT5Er8HCUEB9pv71rdMsZuxIg1/eyvFRGsVSPHqHuKnHpFCovfFEd@HHaVThsZjxnOoDcbnk2Mi0l/MDVmA2dmGO0OX7SaB2aa4STTJHmxpLmkQSB@auAP1PDRZh9fmmC8YvyUVRIvEE6S8cVIY28WqA99a@c3XSnVAEBsDrF3kDKihe5k8EU0uEyvIbbiuYwTHARChZbEtzpEPGhBQnENMtXuKmR6bo6ds2zeZTFTiBoHZcqZyaZPwe1vgbkfNy7w5pTjxQydK43q29xXrlhKKJDk7sUrIdk6icQiXeV@FwtW3t752RcekDH39sF48BGdFKyKsmpMRGA4ykUFZblDxZMupTr0OzpG2TWJthx3/hhLI0gA1VQeElzIprFetUcH/Qbob7EsB6tfJtFllyxVokyxQnaV0iFCjulX8swpxP@0bI2lbztti6MYqD4p3pQl7TpJzvH@tfyhbLe0EY0ITqzgilwmWGw3oQW2lubNMc4S@k0TnYtj7IMYe4txDmKcl2tycqctd@EaKiHOzoN1qtVMx7caOKEQJb252GEcUFIM9YM6XsElxb4PJHc5CX9Yr/m3naahzzy2qxQGI/Fggyl72o8zQV6v2vPcXmPAGcNge7MRfnD1OZ9pdxp3dVE7xWpBnQ6SauAjqGnc@EVdFSupJG8z@f/IjBfKNXmIrWu9h3ova75hXfcNnfL@Xo7wIxowa8Fl4dfvwRXHsHW@P3mg88H0owjkbUIzEkQaUosJ1UJZHP@p6sUDTfUoSAK8Somv7e4TFxHNUjOkiyROCZy7/RT6H1KRu07n/FjFklhHLBXRNb6h0RWCRd7CiUfLLxbt/AcI8jM7kycBCUmUpSzaWZzhwFRZXebkt4FT/4BeUXXpe24OW6qmsT3SCmDgStE5CmOfAHXrawRJYn@9hHbBrHRhJWEFiOnFP3MUA8MZPXtvDPsDVX8S8zwbnsBciv5fzPOzxBOYS9HnM1f29szvz6ij4WS/jOqGul3cGMULHBBnhRcE0fSEuacwxQwOcZrSG2KiHrOTpoh8I4t1xkrFvSYJgfK5JOyfkGMa2LRJfW7Qg3eXA7cZdgwpcJPXmYNmqYXTi@DxExCBy4r6S4qG/bJtqUvnjB/Q22x@LJYBvko3xvDnc2v22ZudeT17ZDlefzjdGKPtJJ8bDW1nYwSXAQaBAGfw/gc)`<TiO>-IDE`

```
                    use Time;

var aStopWATCH_RND_GEN: Time.Timer;
var aStopWATCH_LIN_ALG: Time.Timer;
var aStopWATCH_MAT_REC: Time.Timer;
var aStopWATCH_ARR_REC: Time.Timer;

config const n_power =         5;
config const L_size  =      1000;
       const indices = 1..L_size;
       const aDomain = {indices, indices};

       var   A: [aDomain] real(64);
       var   B: [aDomain] real(64);
       const dtype =    "-real(64)";
       var   S: [aDomain] real(64);

use Random;
/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/     aStopWATCH_RND_GEN.start();
    Random.fillRandom(  A );
    Random.fillRandom(  B );
/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/     aStopWATCH_RND_GEN.stop();

proc arrMUL( arrA: [?DA] real(64),
             arrB: [?DB] real(64)
             ) {

     var     arrC: [aDomain] real(64);

     forall      (row, col) in    aDomain {
             arrC[row, col]  = 0;
        for                              i in arrA.dim( 2 ) do
             arrC[row, col] += arrA[row, i]
                             * arrB[     i, col];
     }
     return  arrC;
}

proc arr_REC_POW( arrM: [?D] real(64),
                  n:          int(64)
                  ):    [ D] real(64) {

     if      n < 1 then return         arrM;
     else               return arrMUL( arrM, arr_REC_POW( arrM, n - 1 ) );
}

/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/     aStopWATCH_ARR_REC.start();
   forall (row, col)             in S.domain {
         S[row, col] = arr_REC_POW( A, n_power )[row,col]
                     + arr_REC_POW( B, n_power )[row,col];
   }
/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/     aStopWATCH_ARR_REC.start();

     use LinearAlgebra;
var mA = LinearAlgebra.Matrix( A );
var mB = LinearAlgebra.Matrix( B );
var mS = LinearAlgebra.Matrix( S );
/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/     aStopWATCH_LIN_ALG.start();
    mS = LinearAlgebra.matPlus( LinearAlgebra.matPow( mA, n_power ),
                                LinearAlgebra.matPow( mB, n_power )
                                );
/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/     aStopWATCH_LIN_ALG.stop();

proc mat_REC_POW( matM: [] real(64),
                  n:        int(64)
                  ) {

     if      n < 1 then return                    matM;
     else               return LinearAlgebra.dot( matM, mat_REC_POW( matM, n - 1 ) );
}

/* -----------------------------------------------re-fill-m?[,]-----*/
    Random.fillRandom(  A ); mA = Matrix( A ); // re-fill mA[,]
    Random.fillRandom(  B ); mB = Matrix( B ); // re-fill mB[,]
/* -----------------------------------------------re-fill-m?[,]-----*/

/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/     aStopWATCH_MAT_REC.start();
   forall  (row, col)              in mS.domain {
         mS[row, col]  = mat_REC_POW( mA, n_power )[row,col]
                       + mat_REC_POW( mB, n_power )[row,col];
   }
/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/     aStopWATCH_MAT_REC.start();

/* |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| PERF--*/

writeln( ".fillRandom() took",           aStopWATCH_RND_GEN.elapsed( Time.TimeUnits.microseconds ), " [us] for A[,], B[,] having ", 2 * ( L_size * L_size ), dtype, " elements in total." );
writeln(
        "\n <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took ", aStopWATCH_LIN_ALG.elapsed( Time.TimeUnits.microseconds ), " [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^b ) for [", L_size, ",", L_size, "] on <TiO>-IDE",
        "\n <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took ", aStopWATCH_MAT_REC.elapsed( Time.TimeUnits.microseconds ), " [us] in [MAT_REC] mode ( A^n + B^b ) for [", L_size, ",", L_size, "] on <TiO>-IDE",
        "\n <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took ", aStopWATCH_ARR_REC.elapsed( Time.TimeUnits.microseconds ), " [us] in [ARR_REC] mode ( A^n + B^b ) for [", L_size, ",", L_size, "] on <TiO>-IDE"
         );
/* ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| INF--*/

writeln(                     "<TiO>-IDE-LocaleSpace is: ", LocaleSpace, " massive. Code is executing [here], being Locale ", here.id  );
for                                                i in    LocaleSpace do
    writeln(                 "          Locale #", i, "'s ID is: ", Locales[i].id );
```

---

Comment: I'm finding this code difficult to read (not a common style of comments & spacing).  Are you able to reduce the problem you are describing to a smaller code snippet? Also, do you consider this a bug report? If so, the [Chapel issues](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues) page may be a better place for that.

Comment: Do you mean inside the rather arcane StackOverflow-code-mini-window, or the full-screen layout view, inside the above URL-ed ( click-through ) inside [The code, live @ `<TiO>-IDE::`]-view ? The `<TiO>-IDE::` evolves, as there were some problems with making BLAS & ATLAC compile ready for `LinearAlgebra` to work, so it also reflects all changes, that were tried during syntax-tuning and compiler-crash investigations ( not to double the work ). While I was not sure the crash is due to be reported, first've asked about some syntax review, if the root cause is not cure-able. Thank you for caring Ben

Comment: I was referring to both, but I now see that TIO is significantly more obfuscated. I tried to compile your example to reproduce the internal error but instead got this error: `bug.chpl:64: error: unresolved call '[domain(2,int(64),false)] real(64).dim(2)'` -- it looks like you're calling `.dim(2)` on an array instead of it's domain. Note that [dim](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/master/builtins/internal/ChapelArray.html#ChapelArray.dim) is only defined on the domain, not the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Task complete! <sup>Domain-helpers were used, recursion still needs some investigation</sup>
<sub>Great thanks to all who helped make this happen.
*prior W.I.P. interim remarks yet left inplace [for educational purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3)*

[OK]: code now passes initial compiler's syntax-check,

 <kbd>BLAS</kbd>+<kbd>ATLAS</kbd> yet fail to work as per v1.15/.16 documentation advice
( and is being solved with the kind help of `<TiO>-IDE` administrators )</sub>

```
                    use Time;

var aStopWATCH_RND_GEN: Time.Timer;
var aStopWATCH_LIN_ALG: Time.Timer;
var aStopWATCH_MAT_REC: Time.Timer;
var aStopWATCH_ARR_REC: Time.Timer;

config const n_power =         5;
config const L_size  =      1000;
       const indices = 1..L_size;
       const aDomain = {indices, indices};

       var   A: [aDomain] real(64);
       var   B: [aDomain] real(64);
       const dtype =    "-real(64)";
       var   S: [aDomain] real(64);

use Random;
/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/     aStopWATCH_RND_GEN.start();
    Random.fillRandom(  A );
    Random.fillRandom(  B );
/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/     aStopWATCH_RND_GEN.stop();

proc arrMUL( arrA: [?DA] real(64),
             arrB: [?DB] real(64)
             ) {

     var     arrC: [aDomain] real(64);

     forall      (row, col) in    aDomain {
             arrC[row, col]  = 0;
     // for                              i in arrA.dim( 2 ) do          // calling .dim(2) on an array instead of it's domain. Note that dim is only defined on the domain, not the array
        for                              i in arrA.domain.dim( 2 ) do   // calling .dim(2) on an array instead of it's domain. Note that dim is only defined on the domain, not the array
             arrC[row, col] += arrA[row, i]
                             * arrB[     i, col];
     }
     return  arrC;
}

proc arr_REC_POW( arrM: [?D] real(64),
                  n:          int(64)
                  ):    [ D] real(64) {

     if      n < 1 then return         arrM;
     else               return arrMUL( arrM, arr_REC_POW( arrM, n - 1 ) );
}

/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/     aStopWATCH_ARR_REC.start();
   forall (row, col)             in S.domain {
         S[row, col] = arr_REC_POW( A, n_power )[row,col]
                     + arr_REC_POW( B, n_power )[row,col];
   }
/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/     aStopWATCH_ARR_REC.start();

     use LinearAlgebra;
var mA = LinearAlgebra.Matrix( A );
var mB = LinearAlgebra.Matrix( B );
var mS = LinearAlgebra.Matrix( S );
/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/     aStopWATCH_LIN_ALG.start();
    mS = LinearAlgebra.matPlus( LinearAlgebra.matPow( mA, n_power ),
                                LinearAlgebra.matPow( mB, n_power )
                                );
/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/     aStopWATCH_LIN_ALG.stop();

proc mat_REC_POW( matM: [?Dm] real(64),
                  n:           int(64)
                  ):    [ Dm] real(64) {

 //  if      n < 1 then return                    matM;                                           // chpl:65: error: unable to resolve return type of function 'mat_REC_POW'
     if      n < 1 then return LinearAlgebra.dot( matM, LinearAlgebra.eye( matM.shape[1] ) );     // [DID NOT HELP]: added: so as to help compiler assume the return-type
     else               return LinearAlgebra.dot( matM,       mat_REC_POW( matM, n - 1 ) );       // chpl:70: error: called recursively at this point
}

/* -----------------------------------------------re-fill-m?[,]-----*/
    Random.fillRandom(  A ); mA = Matrix( A ); // re-fill mA[,]
    Random.fillRandom(  B ); mB = Matrix( B ); // re-fill mB[,]
/* -----------------------------------------------re-fill-m?[,]-----*/

/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/     aStopWATCH_MAT_REC.start();
   forall  (row, col)              in mS.domain {
         mS[row, col]  = mat_REC_POW( mA, n_power )[row,col]
                       + mat_REC_POW( mB, n_power )[row,col];
   }
/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/     aStopWATCH_MAT_REC.start();

/* |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| PERF--*/

writeln( ".fillRandom() took",           aStopWATCH_RND_GEN.elapsed( Time.TimeUnits.microseconds ), " [us] for A[,], B[,] having ", 2 * ( L_size * L_size ), dtype, " elements in total." );
writeln(
        "\n <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took ", aStopWATCH_LIN_ALG.elapsed( Time.TimeUnits.microseconds ), " [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [", L_size, ",", L_size, "] on <TiO>-IDE",
        "\n <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took ", aStopWATCH_MAT_REC.elapsed( Time.TimeUnits.microseconds ), " [us] in [MAT_REC] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [", L_size, ",", L_size, "] on <TiO>-IDE",
        "\n <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took ", aStopWATCH_ARR_REC.elapsed( Time.TimeUnits.microseconds ), " [us] in [ARR_REC] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [", L_size, ",", L_size, "] on <TiO>-IDE"
         );
/* ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| INF--*/

writeln(                     "<TiO>-IDE-LocaleSpace is: ", LocaleSpace, " massive. Code is executing [here], being Locale ", here.id  );
for                                                i in    LocaleSpace do
    writeln(                 "          Locale #", i, "'s ID is: ", Locales[i].id );
```

---

[<kbd>BLAS</kbd> + <kbd>ATLAS</kbd> protest if tried to get compiled/linked **>>> @**](https://tio.run/##3VptU@LIFv7Or@jiVu2oQ0LnPVGvVajsrnUZdAFnqy7XpVpoJTshodJBxp2Z/enrnk4AEwQS0GS2bn9ACKf7efr0eW3sD8mYOk9PU98OqOPuVauo3Ms0zoZj58wbUPFYcBgJHMJOkD0aO3RE3YAEtudmWAS1662LWkP4cHleR91ap1Fr36D29dXVZauDfrxsoW7Ddinxa849vfXJDQLB60a9jPaPSuh57EA52I0y6vzcqtfO6@evolw9QHH6NYaCIUX085j6dsjFcR5R33Mc2g/oAMHjO88fEbdPhQEJCGJDb4qIO0BsMh57foBuqeNNK/E1YUGfIpshcutNAkRgOZcFxA0SUh9I4NufEesThwq2@0B8e1mEDAY2Vw1xkPdA/SElA@TdoT/Re1XF/I@GMeqO2E18EtBNrLGz2hJUYJc2fQCFBB68TwAw5vVtwpU1tYMhADIaTMacKAFV@EBaGHueg35AsI@x7/UpY7Z7D2@pQHyfuPehEbAE3nRo94fxB97kfsiVjUi/701cDgc7Rbab4OIuFCWQKYFTqI0GZOigBply8dHECW0tnMrxH4hjD8JHLCJ8Rwmzbx2K@kPP7tMkJcpPFoS6V7XWTQVNwm3M7TlB1p8rv9uu/xITjbx1YTucBje/5QMYeYMJcEg6SIKL7Tjo0aYOaIGwgPpxxQZgyEyMix9US/GPizFhFHVA@qhUAvtDpB14419rnbOfe63mee@nevMw/FrkL/7RskzjotmrNX7aKPOh1um16mcbZWqt1kuZEjjNnX0f@Q5ye2NvCrv894K6dpSUaPSY/QdFcwlZx3jh9JGE7Q7gRBlISKIYiS9JkHNvRGwXJL7MhCvzWd@OFhrk7CFwHKLuTP4GgZE7e7r6HGYimdONMhHmIHgc04h1WZjLlJcWaq9eqMTPrwXByBsdlSCwCduMdv2sc3HZFK6b5/WW0Km3O4JwUI3M9oUdiBC//GBvRj6CFO/ACKO3e6APtOHLU/5l3gS9Mec3z6aoHKewv4jNnvcJlSsoy1iBQh0yZnSw92yq164dMHFk932PUTjSAUP7sUhWRt0JuwkdvdatQCQ4hVc0JA/cUYGHjA7Q3tx4D@Zv9iuRXVRgPo1CAANLBPaQn8Qwn5UWDpyIHZFzjWpgUYnnYpRu9qJzCmVO18qcLmTaa2XaIYl8znQWWJJGt4LLiARXzoTtrXjsTfdAC5VF4NivlNKOe80ip7FFUtfIzcyfVRKZOaB83Xmgq3rrR45Syuouu7tCfh4wpz4/lPL/3OOXyjxZtYe5NrfcA@B3Z1PDHE2BeO03F71Hp/C6H@6xC0jRHmBaJf7hBkHhcdyxL0@Ei/N6mdOGkr@yBe1ZMt2F9mzqd6E9y@@70J5NfRvaMQ/9@grnuWgu@86qUV5gCw2P1/jtMenzruCQayf2iO93BEW0/UBFxFsk3jnQz7Q/CbiHdHkzAV5zS/mnaB5fgT8W7UG4obt5vZl92Fy9POjFuA28UEtrt1WOxcqIx7@AiA0beMfQxXlyb6xr3wC/yjakwKbSRGZxgyCXjCgv2Y975fTQnmXEaPO1MxMv904y0/6CoBVrHJaTX74Bf/DIOP/J6Ooa0qLj3dvwEPLmHXEYbAl6J94j8P4GKs7An4SBlp/sV/TxotVZZvaWFJdUPKMY61sjislRLMU0LYZ0NmuxU79sfU8tzihu0mLeFHfRYnj4c4rf0FWYGMr/KC2upJjZ80fkM3r7QAWrdgj7dEX8jOGqjN79PmHBO6F7dtk8u2616s3OjRDAGt97K/DGaQek/6kd5u8MWxGep1z8ty6W34TRrKl5TX3QqrcPS6X15XR0faFjw1A2lcZIxuFYXAqsqIPR8SnvF85q7foJpODmjne6KWRlTZYsGW8ka6aTTUMxJEPVNqNYuvlKFEVXsLl5L5KkyakoKTCqKltpMEoGmBQUrJr8JviVKFBXg@kkr4n30ZSw2d0iFJ@TALlegNgjfIbOmEdy5zFVCYalSNJmelr6iaIUGA1rGtZfD7NKC2lb1MCctJQTyOIaMNZ3U4ooW5au0ffY2KIP5TegFf6S7IQAaG1j8gWLIv62dTeCSy8bA/zcEuBSxsQSL@oD25N7J1lnzupqaV4jSvMyR1pk6tIW2U1dnyW3WcZUTFPH5lKe2nTSMCQNXAZjvM1JY37SePmkNyWHFA6GaWJlOw4y5yC/sLaNOLKGLVXaDkflOOp2OIoEEcLaDmeN92zGCf20ABxVsbC6HY7JccxsOP@5aDQEOtiydApxFG6LygtbrDxHwwqXWB0PE7GWE4Ct/Yk0UUdd2Cf/WQu855//E/kOhehvvR3H21d8oG5emkK20TalNflVBR@AyJaBcwdRFV3PG8TAsiXlDqJhM/edmJok57wTXZQ1XdXyBjEMCyt5g1i6pci5g5gGfhM/2ZBSZBHrmmICir5FSuFlSkXCW6QuwIFzkYvAMQ1ZKwBHklXLKAJHwYZUAA5UcEYReoNKRCkCR5F1Qy0CR4FGvAgczcJv5ae7lFJF/@tecaXU7hQ3FiCmrsm51waKEQahfEFUS8q9yjElxbRyBzEgC@UNYsmSmXttIGMrb3XpUKjrWM8dBMqc/ItCSTbyL6U0RdWsAlKBZuhWESlUs6ywh8obR5fMQvRmQOVRxH4MXSmkBDU1zSyidLdkrBWDI@MiSinLME3jzUqp7Jfq8fE@7Z8DFxfhWa/ik7XQx5Sb@UohV@@V7e7e@dX7/Ob9@eI98yLrbt13@z042wkpGfS1enwsiaK4w48jyv/rjyOlg@rT01/9O4fcsydBGPu2Gwh9bzSCnA4PnFvoP56ERnXC/Kpj3@pqNWxJnua9yd8) **`<TiO>-IDE`**, whereas admins confirmed to have been installed and reviewed / acknowledged the both modules to be in-place ( **[OK]: solved** with `<TiO>-IDE` site-admins and Brad - both deserve great thanks for this )

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latlas
```

---

### <sub>`<TiO>-IDE` admin's + Brad's advice helped to get it work</sub>

process-performance on a single-locale, ( threaded version <kbd>ATLAS</kbd> ):

```
.fillRandom()         took  582125 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 2000000-real(64) elements in total.    
 <SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took 2702530 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [1000,1000] on <TiO>-IDE
```

---

### <kbd>`--print-commands`</kbd> compiler-switch reported

```
gcc    -I/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/third-party/qthread/install/linux64-gnu-native-flat/include
       -I/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/third-party/hwloc/install/linux64-gnu-native-flat/include
       -DCHPL_TASKS_MODEL_H=\"tasks-qthreads.h\"
       -DCHPL_THREADS_MODEL_H=\"threads-none.h\"
       -DCHPL_WIDE_POINTER_STRUCT
       -DCHPL_JEMALLOC_PREFIX=chpl_je_
       -DCHPL_HAS_GMP
       -Wno-unused
       -Wno-uninitialized
       -Wno-pointer-sign
       -Wno-tautological-compare
       -Wno-stringop-overflow
       -Wno-strict-overflow
       -c
       -o /tmp/chpl-runner-15040.deleteme/.bin.tio.tmp.o
       -I/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/third-party/qthread/install/linux64-gnu-native-flat/include
       -I.
       -I/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/runtime/include/localeModels/flat
       -I/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/runtime/include/localeModels
       -I/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/runtime/include/comm/none
       -I/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/runtime/include/comm
       -I/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/runtime/include/tasks/qthreads
       -I/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/runtime/include/threads/none
       -I/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/runtime/include
       -I/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/runtime/include/qio
       -I/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/runtime/include/atomics/intrinsics
       -I/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/runtime/include/mem/jemalloc
       -I/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/third-party/utf8-decoder
       -I/opt/chapel/share/chapel/1.16/runtime//../build/runtime/linux64/gnu/arch-native/loc-flat/comm-none/tasks-qthreads/tmr-generic/unwind-none/mem-jemalloc/atomics-intrinsics/gmp/hwloc/re2/wide-struct/fs-none/include
       -I/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/third-party/jemalloc/install/linux64-gnu-native/include
       -I/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/third-party/gmp/install/linux64-gnu-native/include
       -I/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/third-party/hwloc/install/linux64-gnu-native-flat/include /tmp/chpl-runner-15040.deleteme/_main.c

g++    -L/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/third-party/qthread/install/linux64-gnu-native-flat/lib
       -Wl,-rpath,/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/third-party/qthread/install/linux64-gnu-native-flat/lib
       -L/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/third-party/jemalloc/install/linux64-gnu-native/lib
       -L/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/third-party/gmp/install/linux64-gnu-native/lib
       -Wl,-rpath,/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/third-party/gmp/install/linux64-gnu-native/lib
       -L/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/third-party/hwloc/install/linux64-gnu-native-flat/lib
       -Wl,-rpath,/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/third-party/hwloc/install/linux64-gnu-native-flat/lib
       -L/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/third-party/re2/install/linux64-gnu-native/lib
       -Wl,-rpath,/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/third-party/re2/install/linux64-gnu-native/lib
       -o /tmp/chpl-runner-15040.deleteme/.bin.tio.tmp
       -L/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/runtime/lib/linux64/gnu/arch-native/loc-flat/comm-none/tasks-qthreads/tmr-generic/unwind-none/mem-jemalloc/atomics-intrinsics/gmp/hwloc/re2/wide-struct/fs-none
       /tmp/chpl-runner-15040.deleteme/.bin.tio.tmp.o
       /opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/runtime/lib/linux64/gnu/arch-native/loc-flat/comm-none/tasks-qthreads/tmr-generic/unwind-none/mem-jemalloc/atomics-intrinsics/gmp/hwloc/re2/wide-struct/fs-none/main.o
       -lchpl
       -lm
       -lblas -L/usr/lib64/atlas
       -ltatlas
       -lgmp
       -lchpl
       -lqthread -L/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/third-party/hwloc/install/linux64-gnu-native-flat/lib
       -L/opt/chapel//lib/chapel/1.16/third-party/jemalloc/install/linux64-gnu-native/lib
       -ljemalloc
       -lhwloc
       -lm
       -lre2
       -lpthread
```

---

### <sup>Last, but not least, let me share</sup>
Some final remarks
<sub>on performance-data[,](https://tio.run/##3VptU@LIFv7Or@jiVu2oQ0LnPVGvVajsrnUZdAFnqy7XpVpoJTshodJBxp2Z/enrnk4AEwQS0GS2bn9ACKf7efr0eW3sD8mYOk9PU98OqOPuVauo3Ms0zoZj58wbUPFYcBgJHMJOkD0aO3RE3YAEtudmWAS1662LWkP4cHleR91ap1Fr36D29dXVZauDfrxsoW7Ddinxa849vfXJDQLB60a9jPaPSuh57EA52I0y6vzcqtfO6@evolw9QHH6NYaCIUX085j6dsjFcR5R33Mc2g/oAMHjO88fEbdPhQEJCGJDb4qIO0BsMh57foBuqeNNK/E1YUGfIpshcutNAkRgOZcFxA0SUh9I4NufEesThwq2@0B8e1mEDAY2Vw1xkPdA/SElA@TdoT/Re1XF/I@GMeqO2E18EtBNrLGz2hJUYJc2fQCFBB68TwAw5vVtwpU1tYMhADIaTMacKAFV@EBaGHueg35AsI@x7/UpY7Z7D2@pQHyfuPehEbAE3nRo94fxB97kfsiVjUi/701cDgc7Rbab4OIuFCWQKYFTqI0GZOigBply8dHECW0tnMrxH4hjD8JHLCJ8Rwmzbx2K@kPP7tMkJcpPFoS6V7XWTQVNwm3M7TlB1p8rv9uu/xITjbx1YTucBje/5QMYeYMJcEg6SIKL7Tjo0aYOaIGwgPpxxQZgyEyMix9US/GPizFhFHVA@qhUAvtDpB14419rnbOfe63mee@nevMw/FrkL/7RskzjotmrNX7aKPOh1um16mcbZWqt1kuZEjjNnX0f@Q5ye2NvCrv894K6dpSUaPSY/QdFcwlZx3jh9JGE7Q7gRBlISKIYiS9JkHNvRGwXJL7MhCvzWd@OFhrk7CFwHKLuTP4GgZE7e7r6HGYimdONMhHmIHgc04h1WZjLlJcWaq9eqMTPrwXByBsdlSCwCduMdv2sc3HZFK6b5/WW0Km3O4JwUI3M9oUdiBC//GBvRj6CFO/ACKO3e6APtOHLU/5l3gS9Mec3z6aoHKewv4jNnvcJlSsoy1iBQh0yZnSw92yq164dMHFk932PUTjSAUP7sUhWRt0JuwkdvdatQCQ4hVc0JA/cUYGHjA7Q3tx4D@Zv9iuRXVRgPo1CAANLBPaQn8Qwn5UWDpyIHZFzjWpgUYnnYpRu9qJzCmVO18qcLmTaa2XaIYl8znQWWJJGt4LLiARXzoTtrXjsTfdAC5VF4NivlNKOe80ip7FFUtfIzcyfVRKZOaB83Xmgq3rrR45Syuouu7tCfh4wpz4/lPL/3OOXyjxZtYe5NrfcA@B3Z1PDHE2BeO03F71Hp/C6H@6xC0jRHmBaJf7hBkHhcdyxL0@Ei/N6mdOGkr@yBe1ZMt2F9mzqd6E9y@@70J5NfRvaMQ/9@grnuWgu@86qUV5gCw2P1/jtMenzruCQayf2iO93BEW0/UBFxFsk3jnQz7Q/CbiHdHkzAV5zS/mnaB5fgT8W7UG4obt5vZl92Fy9POjFuA28UEtrt1WOxcqIx7@AiA0beMfQxXlyb6xr3wC/yjakwKbSRGZxgyCXjCgv2Y975fTQnmXEaPO1MxMv904y0/6CoBVrHJaTX74Bf/DIOP/J6Ooa0qLj3dvwEPLmHXEYbAl6J94j8P4GKs7An4SBlp/sV/TxotVZZvaWFJdUPKMY61sjislRLMU0LYZ0NmuxU79sfU8tzihu0mLeFHfRYnj4c4rf0FWYGMr/KC2upJjZ80fkM3r7QAWrdgj7dEX8jOGqjN79PmHBO6F7dtk8u2616s3OjRDAGt97K/DGaQek/6kd5u8MWxGep1z8ty6W34TRrKl5TX3QqrcPS6X15XR0faFjw1A2lcZIxuFYXAqsqIPR8SnvF85q7foJpODmjne6KWRlTZYsGW8ka6aTTUMxJEPVNqNYuvlKFEVXsLl5L5KkyakoKTCqKltpMEoGmBQUrJr8JviVKFBXg@kkr4n30ZSw2d0iFJ@TALlegNgjfIbOmEdy5zFVCYalSNJmelr6iaIUGA1rGtZfD7NKC2lb1MCctJQTyOIaMNZ3U4ooW5au0ffY2KIP5TegFf6S7IQAaG1j8gWLIv62dTeCSy8bA/zcEuBSxsQSL@oD25N7J1lnzupqaV4jSvMyR1pk6tIW2U1dnyW3WcZUTFPH5lKe2nTSMCQNXAZjvM1JY37SePmkNyWHFA6GaWJlOw4y5yC/sLaNOLKGLVXaDkflOOp2OIoEEcLaDmeN92zGCf20ABxVsbC6HY7JccxsOP@5aDQEOtiydApxFG6LygtbrDxHwwqXWB0PE7GWE4Ct/Yk0UUdd2Cf/WQu855//E/kOhehvvR3H21d8oG5emkK20TalNflVBR@AyJaBcwdRFV3PG8TAsiXlDqJhM/edmJok57wTXZQ1XdXyBjEMCyt5g1i6pci5g5gGfhM/2ZBSZBHrmmICir5FSuFlSkXCW6QuwIFzkYvAMQ1ZKwBHklXLKAJHwYZUAA5UcEYReoNKRCkCR5F1Qy0CR4FGvAgczcJv5ae7lFJF/@tecaXU7hQ3FiCmrsm51waKEQahfEFUS8q9yjElxbRyBzEgC@UNYsmSmXttIGMrb3XpUKjrWM8dBMqc/ItCSTbyL6U0RdWsAlKBZuhWESlUs6ywh8obR5fMQvRmQOVRxH4MXSmkBDU1zSyidLdkrBWDI@MiSinLME3jzUqp7Jfq8fE@7Z8DFxfhWa/ik7XQx5Sb@UohV@@V7e7e@dX7/Ob9@eI98yLrbt13@z042wkpGfS1enwsiaK4w48jyv/rjyOlg@rT01/9O4fcsydBGPu2Gwh9bzSCnA4PnFvoP56ERnXC/Kpj3@pqNWxJnua9yd8) setup overheads and a range of experimentally explorable boundaries</sub>

While the biggest [chapel](/questions/tagged/chapel) **`[PAR]`** powers were outside the scope-of-testability ( administratively not available for obvious reasons on the public sponsored `<TiO>-IDE` infrastructure ) and might get further investigated on more realistic computing devices, as those that are for example available within the Cray's internal resources available and used by Cray's Chapel-initiative, **the essence of both the benefits from the [chapel](/questions/tagged/chapel) language expressivity and those from the actual state of the language implementation** is impressive.

Some additional issues to be investigated may be:

- an observed **`Random.fillRandom()`** performance **`< 22+   [ns/B]`** generated & stored,
  compared to `py3.numpy.random.rand()` peaking **`~    1.54 [ns/B]`** generated & stored
  on identical physical infrastructure
- `LinearAlgebra.` methods, yet to get tested on large-scale, dense `.Matrix` instances, where multi-locale, distributed, [**`[PAR]` enabled computing infrastructures** ought demonstrate the powers and bring in the remarkable gains expected](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3)

---

### Acknowledgements

Once more, thank you Dennis @`<TiO>-IDE` support & Brad @ Cray + all the best to the [chapel](/questions/tagged/chapel) Team, driving and extending this great software Project still grow better and better.

---

```
writeln(// "______________________________________ChplCode.<-lsatlas> implementation___________________________________ SERIAL-MODE [ATLAS] SUPPORT FOR [LinearAlgebra] MODULE" );
           "______________________________________ChplCode.<-ltatlas> implementation_________________________________ THREADED-MODE [ATLAS] SUPPORT FOR [LinearAlgebra] MODULE" );
        /* 
           As the experimentally collected performance-data show and support below,
           there is about a constant,
           Matrix scale-invariant,
           additional overhead of ~ +440 ~ +500 [ms]
           for
           a THREADED-MODE [ATLAS] SUPPORT FOR [LinearAlgebra] MODULE,
           believed to be
           associated with a setup of a thread-pool & al processing pre-arrangements,
           which
           ought be accounted for in
           an overhead-aware Amdahl Law formulation for pre-validations of a feasible choice
           whether a [PAR], using -ltatlas
           or      a [SEQ], using -lsatlas support for the [LinearAlgebra] module implementation
           will yield faster processing times.
           */

                    use Time;

var aStopWATCH_RND_GEN: Time.Timer;
var aStopWATCH_LIN_ALG: Time.Timer;
var aStopWATCH_MAT_REC: Time.Timer;
var aStopWATCH_ARR_REC: Time.Timer;

config const n_power =         5;
config const L_size  =      2600;
       const indices = 1..L_size;
       const aDomain = {indices, indices};

       var   A: [aDomain] real(64);
       var   B: [aDomain] real(64);
       const dtype =    "-real(64)";
       var   S: [aDomain] real(64);

use Random;
/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/     aStopWATCH_RND_GEN.start();
    Random.fillRandom(  A );
    Random.fillRandom(  B );
/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/     aStopWATCH_RND_GEN.stop();
writeln( ".fillRandom()        took ",                                     aStopWATCH_RND_GEN.elapsed( Time.TimeUnits.microseconds ),
         " [us] for A[,], B[,] having ", 2 * ( L_size * L_size ), dtype, " elements in total." );

     use LinearAlgebra;
var mA = LinearAlgebra.Matrix( A );
var mB = LinearAlgebra.Matrix( B );
var mS = LinearAlgebra.Matrix( S );

/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/     aStopWATCH_LIN_ALG.start();
    mS = LinearAlgebra.matPlus( LinearAlgebra.matPow( mA, n_power ),
                                LinearAlgebra.matPow( mB, n_power )
                                );
/* ---------------------------------------------SECTION-UNDER-TEST--*/     aStopWATCH_LIN_ALG.stop();
/* |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| PERF--*/

writeln( ".fillRandom()        took ", aStopWATCH_RND_GEN.elapsed( Time.TimeUnits.microseconds ), " [us] for A[,], B[,] having ", 2 * ( L_size * L_size ), dtype, " elements in total." );
writeln(
       "\n<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took ", aStopWATCH_LIN_ALG.elapsed( Time.TimeUnits.microseconds ), " [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [", L_size, ",", L_size, "] on <TiO>-IDE"
   // ,"\n<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took ", aStopWATCH_MAT_REC.elapsed( Time.TimeUnits.microseconds ), " [us] in [MAT_REC] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [", L_size, ",", L_size, "] on <TiO>-IDE"
   // ,"\n<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took ", aStopWATCH_ARR_REC.elapsed( Time.TimeUnits.microseconds ), " [us] in [ARR_REC] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [", L_size, ",", L_size, "] on <TiO>-IDE"
        );
/* ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| INF--*/

writeln(                     "<TiO>-IDE-LocaleSpace is: ", LocaleSpace, " massive. Code is executing [here], being Locale ", here.id  );
for                                                i in    LocaleSpace do
    writeln(                 "          Locale #", i, "'s ID is: ", Locales[i].id,                                            "\n                                having a name of <_",
                                                                    Locales[i].name,                                        "_>\n                                having { REAL:"              ,
                                                                 // Locales[i].numPUs( logical = false, accessible =  true ),   " | VIRT:"                       ,
                                                                    Locales[i].numPUs(           false,               true ),   " | VIRT:"                       ,
                                                                 // Locales[i].numPUs( logical =  true, accessible =  true ),   " | TEOR:"                       ,
                                                                    Locales[i].numPUs(            true,               true ),   " | TEOR:"                       ,
                                                                 // Locales[i].numPUs( logical =  true, accessible = false ),   " } PUnits"                      ,
                                                                    Locales[i].numPUs(            true,              false ),   " } PUnits\n                                having max ",
                                                                    Locales[i].maxTaskPar,                                      " 'just'-[CONCURRENT]-tasks\n                                having max ",
                                                                    Locales[i].callStackSize,                                   "-callStackSIZE."
                                                                    );

/* ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| RES:

.fillRandom()        took      560773 [us] for A[,], B[,] having  2000000-real(64) elements in total. <BEST-CASE>s IN SERIAL-MODE [ATLAS] SUPPORT FOR [LinearAlgebra] MODULE
.fillRandom()        took     2521920 [us] for A[,], B[,] having  8000000-real(64) elements in total.
.fillRandom()        took     2717450 [us] for A[,], B[,] having  9680000-real(64) elements in total.
.fillRandom()        took     3630820 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 11520000-real(64) elements in total.

.fillRandom()        took     4429820 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 13520000-real(64) elements in total.
.fillRandom()        took     4048440 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 13520000-real(64) elements in total. ( IN THREADED-MODE ) was faster, but not systematically

.fillRandom()        took     4793110 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 15680000-real(64) elements in total. 
.fillRandom()        took     5055060 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 15680000-real(64) elements in total. ( IN THREADED-MODE )

.fillRandom()        took     5630540 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 18000000-real(64) elements in total.



<TiO>-IDE-LocaleSpace is: {0..0} massive. Code is executing [here], being Locale 0
          Locale #0's ID is: 0
                                having a name of <_tio2_>
                                having { REAL:1 | VIRT:1 | TEOR:1 } PUnits
                                having max 4 'just'-[CONCURRENT]-tasks
                                having max 8388608-callStackSIZE.

<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took    15110000 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [2000,2000] on <TiO>-IDE <BEST-CASE>s IN SERIAL-MODE
<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took    17880300 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [2200,2200] on <TiO>-IDE
<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took    25094100 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [2400,2400] on <TiO>-IDE
<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took    31550900 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [2600,2600] on <TiO>-IDE
<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took    32996500 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [2600,2600] on <TiO>-IDE
<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took    34390400 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [2800,2800] on <TiO>-IDE
<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> KILL-ed                                               for [3000,3000] on <TiO>-IDE, having 18,000,000-real(64) elements .fillRandom()-ed in ~ 5.6 [s] time.

______________________________________ChplCode.<-lsatlas> implementation___________________________________ SERIAL-MODE [ATLAS] SUPPORT FOR [LinearAlgebra] MODULE
                                                  ^________________________________________________________ SERIAL-MODE [ATLAS] SUPPORT FOR [LinearAlgebra] MODULE
.fillRandom()        took 5.60773e+05 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 2000000-real(64) elements in total.
.fillRandom()        took 5.62970e+05 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 2000000-real(64) elements in total.
.fillRandom()        took 5.64366e+05 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 2000000-real(64) elements in total.
.fillRandom()        took 5.70291e+05 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 2000000-real(64) elements in total.
.fillRandom()        took 5.75086e+05 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 2000000-real(64) elements in total.
.fillRandom()        took 5.85121e+05 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 2000000-real(64) elements in total.
.fillRandom()        took 6.25645e+05 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 2000000-real(64) elements in total.
.fillRandom()        took 6.77903e+05 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 2000000-real(64) elements in total.
.fillRandom()        took 6.96932e+05 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 2000000-real(64) elements in total.
.fillRandom()        took 6.98700e+05 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 2000000-real(64) elements in total.

<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took 2.06538e+06 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [1000,1000] on <TiO>-IDE
<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took 2.07902e+06 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [1000,1000] on <TiO>-IDE
<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took 2.08725e+06 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [1000,1000] on <TiO>-IDE
<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took 2.12497e+06 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [1000,1000] on <TiO>-IDE
<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took 2.13071e+06 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [1000,1000] on <TiO>-IDE
<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took 2.22075e+06 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [1000,1000] on <TiO>-IDE
<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took 2.28035e+06 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [1000,1000] on <TiO>-IDE
<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took 2.32674e+06 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [1000,1000] on <TiO>-IDE
<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took 2.33844e+06 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [1000,1000] on <TiO>-IDE
<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took 2.35908e+06 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [1000,1000] on <TiO>-IDE


______________________________________ChplCode.<-ltatlas> implementation_________________________________ THREADED-MODE [ATLAS] SUPPORT FOR [LinearAlgebra] MODULE
                                                  ^______________________________________________________ THREADED-MODE [ATLAS] SUPPORT FOR [LinearAlgebra] MODULE
.fillRandom()        took 5.68652e+05 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 2000000-real(64) elements in total.
.fillRandom()        took 5.73797e+05 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 2000000-real(64) elements in total.
.fillRandom()        took 5.74911e+05 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 2000000-real(64) elements in total.
.fillRandom()        took 5.81389e+05 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 2000000-real(64) elements in total.
.fillRandom()        took 5.87079e+05 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 2000000-real(64) elements in total.
.fillRandom()        took 5.92182e+05 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 2000000-real(64) elements in total.
.fillRandom()        took 6.20989e+05 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 2000000-real(64) elements in total.
.fillRandom()        took 6.62606e+05 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 2000000-real(64) elements in total.
.fillRandom()        took 6.69875e+05 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 2000000-real(64) elements in total.
.fillRandom()        took 6.71270e+05 [us] for A[,], B[,] having 2000000-real(64) elements in total.

<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took 2.53459e+06 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [1000,1000] on <TiO>-IDE
<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took 2.57695e+06 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [1000,1000] on <TiO>-IDE
<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took 2.59966e+06 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [1000,1000] on <TiO>-IDE
<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took 2.61859e+06 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [1000,1000] on <TiO>-IDE
<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took 2.70356e+06 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [1000,1000] on <TiO>-IDE
<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took 2.76325e+06 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [1000,1000] on <TiO>-IDE
<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took 2.85588e+06 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [1000,1000] on <TiO>-IDE
<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took 2.92058e+06 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [1000,1000] on <TiO>-IDE
<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took 2.92204e+06 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [1000,1000] on <TiO>-IDE
<SECTION-UNDER-TEST> took 2.97887e+06 [us] in [LIN_ALG] mode ( A^n + B^n ) for [1000,1000] on <TiO>-IDE


<TiO>-IDE-LocaleSpace is: {0..0} massive.             +--------------------------------<_tio2_>
Code is executing [here], being Locale 0              V
          Locale #0's ID is: 0, having a name of <_tio2_>
                                having { REAL:1 | VIRT:1 | TEOR:1 } PUnits,
                                having max 4 just-[CONCURENT]-tasks,
                                having 8388608-callStackSIZE.

                                                      +--------------------------------<_tio3_>
                                                      V
...                             having a name of <_tio3_>
                                having { REAL:1 | VIRT:1 | TEOR:1 } PUnits
                                having max 4 'just'-[CONCURRENT]-tasks
                                having max 8388608-callStackSIZE.


*/
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the TIO setup, but might it be necessary to add `-L` flags to point the Chapel compiler to the installed location of the blas and atlas libraries?  To debug, you might try adding a `--print-commands` flag to your `chpl` compiler command line which will show the underlying C compile + link commands that are invoked by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks, Brad, it was setup -- if you just click-through to open the TiO-IDE, scoll to the very top, there is a section [ Compiler flags ] and, having unfolded these options, you would see all these to have been set, as requested inside [ Chapel ] documentation for LinearAlgebra and its underlying BLAS package. ( A nice thing of the TiO-IDE is right its capability to provide a ( semi-)-persistent URL to a fully-equipped state-full-IDE-environment ( i.e. altogether with flags and settings - just scroll / un-fold and +set/-remove whatever is needed in compilation / linking / launch phases ).

Comment: When I click through, I see the compiler flag: `-I$PATH_TO_CBLAS_DIR` but I believe that the intention of the documentation is that you either replace $PATH_TO_CBLAS_DIR with the path to the CBLAS directory or else set a variable in the environment with this name whose value is the directory.  Ditto `-L$PATH_TO_BLAS_LIBS`.  If I add the `--print-commands` flag suggested in my previous comment, I see `-IATH_TO_CBLAS_DIR` in the C compilation line and `-LATH_TO_BLAS_LIBS` in the linker line, which are presumably not intended.

Comment: Thank you, Brad. <TiO>-IDE admins have fixed the issue, will update the status in full detail